# Why we can always choose $n_{k+1}>n_k$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E$ is a complex inner product space and $(x_n)_{n},(y_n)_{n}\subseteq E$ are **unit** sequences.

If we suppose that it is not true that there is a constant $c<1$ such that
$$|\langle x_n|y_n\rangle|\leq c <1 ,$$
 for all $n$ sufficiently large.

Therefore, for every positive integer $k$, the number $c_k=1-1/k$ does not satisfy
$$|\langle x_n|y_n\rangle|\leq 1-1/k ,\tag{*}$$
 for all $n$ sufficiently large, which means that it is not true that there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$ the inequality $(*)$ is valid.

Therefore, there exists some $n_k$ such that 
$$1\geq |\langle x_{n_k}|y_{n_k}\rangle|> 1-1/k, $$
 where the inequality $1\geq |\langle x_{n_k}|y_{n_k}\rangle|$ follows from the fact that $x_n,y_n$ are unit vectors.

Hence
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}|\langle x_{n_k}|y_{n_k}\rangle|=1.$$

> Why we can always choose $n_{k+1}>n_k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contrapositive of the statement "There exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that
$$
|\langle x_n|y_n\rangle|\leq 1-1/k
$$
holds for all $n\ge N$" is

> "For each $N\in \Bbb N$, we can find $m > N$ such that 
>   $$
> |\langle x_m|y_m\rangle| > 1-1/k
> $$
>   holds."

Now, we just take $N=n_k$ and take $n_{k+1}$ to be $m$ from the above statement.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Please how can I write correctely the  sentence ''there is a constant $\theta<1$ such that
$|\langle x_n|y_n\rangle|\leq c <1 $ for all $n$ sufficiently large.'' ? It is true to write ''there is a constant $\theta<1$ and  $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have
$$|\langle x_n|y_n\rangle|\leq c <1. $$ ?

Comment: @Schüler You are correct.